# Why Running torchscript model inference on IOS results in threading error?

Tags: ios, multithreading, pytorch, dispatch-queue, torchscript

I have been trying to integrate pytorch model developed on python into IOS. The example I have looked at is from this [github repo](https://github.com/pytorch/ios-demo-app/blob/master/D2Go).

I used the same d2go model in my own application. One thing I noticed is that if the model inference code isn't wrapped in the DispatchQueue global as shown below

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    guard let outputs = self.inferencer.module.detect(image: &pixelBuffer) else {
        return
    }
```

I get a error like `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeeb4e0000)` or if my model takes too long to run the inference even though it is wrapped in the dispatchQueue code above, I get an error like `Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ff159bed010)`.

Im not sure how threading works in such scenarios. I am running the code when a button is pressed in the new SwiftUI framework.

Any Intuition on why such a case might happen ? I have tried the above on simulators

Answer (score 0):

You should probably declare "pixelBuffer" in the same scope (inside the dispatch block)

Comment: nope that crashed as well. I am wondering if it is because the model that I am using is 78mb whereas d2go model is only 2 mb large.